# Ajax request doesn't work all times

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

So I have a number inside a div like this

```
<div style="display:inline" id="contItems">0</div>
```

and I am updating this number depending on the amount of items there are inside this cart from the controller and I am returning an Int and I need to replace the number inside the Div with the new Int, so I did this Ajax request:

```
function CountItemsDiv() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/Cart/CountItems',
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                      $('#contItems').html(data);

                }
            });
        }
```

and I call this function CountItemsDiv() when page loads and also when the user adds or removes a product and it works... but not all the times, sometimes it will change the number but some others it will not, I would say it would work 60% of the times someone would click on Add or Remove, I've tried to set cache to false but it still does it, what else could this be?

Comment: What browser are you having this issue on? If possible can you also please provide the network activity when a user clicks Add/Remove (do multiple and point out the failures).

Comment: Yes be sure to use your F12 developer tools in whatever browser you are using. Alternatively, add an error: handler function because the actual `/Cart/CountItems` itself may be failing! Setting `async` to true/false here shouldn't make a difference, because the success function will still only be triggered in either case when the ajax call completes.

Comment: I am using Chrome, but the network activity shows everything fine and the controller works everytime, so the items are being added/removed properly but the Ajax controller that gets that simple number is sometimes not working.

Comment: If there are no 404, or 500 (timeouts) responses from the ajax call then it's likely a server-side issue. It sounds like the `CountItems` is happening before the actual item is removed from the collection. Try changing your `CountItems` call to happen synchronously _after_ a successful `Add/Remove`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need async function in false,async false waiting for request with all items.

```
function CountItemsDiv() {
     $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/Cart/CountItems',
                cache: false,
                async : false,
                success: function (data) {
                      $('#contItems').html(data);

                }
            });
}
```

Comment: This helped, but it is still happening but now I would say it works 80% of the times.